# Spring Boot Hibernate @OneToMany Collections are always null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i try to load some data via repository in spring boot. The main entity is completely fine and contains data. Except the @OneToMany relational collections.
From debug output is see the correct query and it returns data fore sure.

**THE PROBLEM:**

- bookings List is null even if generated SQL is executed and returns results.
- no thread on stackoverflow could solve my problem.

**Here is how i try to do it:**

```
Optional<Ad> pi = adRepository.findById(adID);
if (!pi.isPresent()) {
    return null;
}
Ad ad = pi.get();

List<Booking> bookings = ad.getItem().getBookings();

// bookings is null. why is it not populated?
// i've also tried use FetchType.EAGER. Didn't helped
```

**Ad**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "xxx", name = "AD")
public class Ad {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "adID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional=true, mappedBy="ad", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Item item;
}
```

**Item**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="xxx", name="ITEM")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="adID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Ad ad;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    private List<Booking> bookings;
}
```

**Booking**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "xxx", name = "BOOKING")
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "bookID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "adID", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "adID")
    private Item item;
}
```

**Query generated by Hibernate**

```
select
bookings0_.adID as adID8_34_0_,
bookings0_.bookID as bookID1_34_0_,
bookings0_.bookID as bookID1_34_1_
from xxx.BOOKING bookings0_
where bookings0_.prditmID=1337
```

Is there anything i've missed?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the Item class and the @Id declaration.
Changed to and it works.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="xxx", name="ITEM")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "adID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="adID", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Ad ad;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item")
    private List<Booking> bookings;
}
```